# How can I undo my changes to 'post-revprop-change'?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

In error I edited the 'post-revprop-change' file instead of the 'pre-revprop-change' in the hooks directory.

The edit I made was to copy in the instructions described [here](http://ayria.livejournal.com/33438.html) which allow changes to be made to the log entry. Obviously this doesn't make sense for the 'post-revprop-change' hook so I would like to undo the change. A simple thing would be just to delete the executable, but as I overwrote the template, I would like to know what the know what instructions should exist in this file. Apologies if my question seems convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is created anytime you create a new repository. So just create a new repository, copy the template, and delete the new one.

The template doesn't actually *do* anything, so you lose no functionality if you just delete the file. The same information in the template is [documented in the Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html)